# haystack search with multiple models

Tags: django, django-models, django-haystack

In my project, I have two tables (Users, Languages). Each user has at least one 'Language'.

I want to be able to search by language or location, and see the user's name, language/s, and country as a result.

I have the following models:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=200,default='',blank=True, null=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=200,default='',blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.user)

class Language(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey('UserProfile')
    language = models.CharField(max_length=200,default='',blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.user)
```

What I've managed to do:

```
class UserIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)

    city = indexes.CharField(model_attr='city')
    zip = indexes.CharField(model_attr='zip')
    country = indexes.CharField(model_attr='country')

    def get_model(self):
        return UserProfile
    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        return self.get_model().objects.all()
```

My userprofile_text.txt:

```
{{ object.user.get_full_name }}
{{ object.language}} <-- of course this doesn't work.
{{ object.country}}
{{ object.zip}}
```

I am able to search using name, zip, and country and display results accordingly How do I modify my code so that I'm also able to search by language? Also, how would I show all languages related to each user?

something like:

```
{% for language in result.object.languages %}
{{ language }}
{% endfor %}
```

All I've found on SO so far  are outdated answers or answers unrelated to haystack. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a `ForeignKey` from the `Language` to the `User` [without a `related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name), you need to access `language_set` on the user object:

```
{{ object.user.get_full_name }}
{% for language in object.user.languages %}
    {{ language }}
{% endfor %}
```

This gives you a list of all languages for a user.

---

However, the problem is mostly in your modelling. This chunk:

```
class Language(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey('UserProfile')
```

essentially states that "Every language has exactly one user who speaks it". Which is probably not what you want. Instead use a [`ManyToManyField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield):

```
class Language(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    users = models.ManyToManyField('UserProfile',related_name="spoken_languages")

{{ object.user.get_full_name }}
{% for language in object.user.spoken_languages %}
    {{ language }}
{% endfor %}
```

Which allows a user to speak many languages *and* for a language to be spoken by many users.

Comment: made some progress with this answer. now I'm just trying to figure out how to search by language.